# MySQL Workbench installation failing on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mysql-workbench

I am trying to install MySQL Workbench. I installed mysql server and next downloaded package:

```
mysql-workbench-community-6.3.10-1ubuntu16.04-amd64.deb
```

And I used command:

```
sudo dpkg -i mysql-workbench-community-6.3.10-1ubuntu16.04-amd64.deb
```

But I got:

```
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-workbench-community.
(Reading database ... 467972 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack mysql-workbench-community-6.3.10-1ubuntu16.04-amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-workbench-community (6.3.10-1ubuntu16.04) ...
```

And it seems that **dpkg:** dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-workbench-community:

```
mysql-workbench-community depends on libgeos-c1v5 (>= 3.4.2); however:
   Package libgeos-c1v5 is not installed.
mysql-workbench-community depends on libhdf4-0-alt; however:
   Package libhdf4-0-alt is not installed.
mysql-workbench-community depends on libjasper1; however:
  Package libjasper1 is not installed.
mysql-workbench-community depends on libmysqlclient20 (>= 5.7.11); however:
  Package libmysqlclient20 is not installed.
mysql-workbench-community depends on libnetcdf11 (>= 4.0.1); however:
  Package libnetcdf11 is not installed.
mysql-workbench-community depends on libpng12-0 (>= 1.2.13-4); however:
  Package libpng12-0 is not installed.
 mysql-workbench-community depends on libpq5; however:
  Package libpq5 is not installed.
mysql-workbench-community depends on libxerces-c3.1; however:
  Package libxerces-c3.1 is not installed.
mysql-workbench-community depends on python-crypto; however:
  Package python-crypto is not installed.
**dpkg:** error processing package mysql-workbench-community (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for shared-mime-info (1.8-1) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.17-1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.23-1ubuntu3.17.10.1) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.3+17.10.20170810-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-6ubuntu5) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.60ubuntu1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:  
 mysql-workbench-community
```

Comment: You shouldn’t be installing it via a downloaded `.deb` package. For something like this even if the official repo version is slightly older it doesn’t matter for any practical reasons.

Answer (score 4):

I too have chased this nightmare around and around.

My suggestion is to not attempt to install from a downloaded package.
Your built-in repos should already have it.  At the time of this suggestion, they were 16.04.

Try:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt install mysql-workbench
```

That does the trick for me.. I hope it works for you.

Comment: Thank you it worked for me, but after `mysql-workbench` was installed I got the error `access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'` (on Ubuntu 18.04.3), I solved it by following the instructions [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/793750/408473), I hope this helps those who are comming after ;)

Answer (score 1):

snap install mysql-workbench-community

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).